# why does a sql server query take too long in stress test

Tags: sql-server-2000

Sql server query takes 1 second when run in query analyzer with single user. I started stress tool written by Adam Machanic with same query and run that for 200 users and in parrallel I ran the same query in query analyzer it takes more than when 20 second.

How to find which join or where clause is creating problem in a stress test situation. What is taking so long?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Can you **show us** the query, and explain the context (tables involved etc.) a bit more?? Without anything to go on, it's really really hard to give any sane advice....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely going to be locking and blocking. A starting point is [reading this article on the MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271509) that gives a sproc you can run (and the output of which is *very* verbose). Indexes may be one way to sort it out, but without any more information (schema, query, volumes of data, etc) it's unlikely we can provide more.

Answer (score 0):

see this article: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), it is the most comprehensive article that I've ever seen on this issue.

I'd bet that it is one of [The Default Settings](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings), like `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`.